# iCalendar Spec RRULE Multiple Times?

Tags: icalendar, recurrence, rrule

I'm developing some software which interfaces with the Google Calendar API, and one feature my users will be able to take advantage of is setting multiple event times for a single "class" (i.e. the class is 2-5 on some days and 3-6 on others).

Is it possible for a recurrence rule to specify a different time for different days, allowing me to create one repeating event instead of multiple?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible for a recurrence rule to specify a different time for different days, allowing me to create one repeating event instead of multiple?

No, not really, but you can achieve this result with other methods.

- If there is a pattern, you can combine multiple `RRULE`. For example one repeat every other days starting Monday at 2, the second one repeat every other days starting Tuesday at 3. So the combined result will be Mon at 2, Tue at 3, Wed at 2, and so on. Though note that according to the RFC you *SHOULD NOT* define more than one `RRULE` (see
  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3)

> it SHOULD NOT be specified more than once.
> The recurrence set generated with multiple "RRULE" properties is
> undefined.

So the behavior depends on the actual implementation and I do not know about Google Calendar API. Most libraries I know of do support multiple `RRULE` though, so you should give it a try.

- Again, if there is a pattern, you can also use `BYSETPOS`. It's a bit complicated to wrap your head around this one, but basically you need to generate a set of occurrences (for example, over a week) and then cherry pick the ones that are valid. Try something like this (multi-lines for clarity):

```
DTSTART=20160711T140000
FREQ=WEEKLY
BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
BYHOUR=14,15
BYSETPOS=1,4,5,8,9
```

This will alternate Monday at 2, Tuesday at 3, Wednesday at 2, and so on. Again, you need a clear repetitive pattern for this one to work.

- If there is no pattern and you just want to have some days with a different time, combine your `RRULE` with `RDATE` and `EXDATE` to add or remove special occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple `RRULE` on Google Calendar but I do not recommend it. See the [`v3` API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) -- `recurrence[]`. Pass an array of strings.

While Google Calendar will respect multiple `RRULE`, Apple Calendar currently will only use one. This means that anyone uses Apple Calendar on their laptop/phone (synced from Google Calendar) will not see all recurrences.

Also, even though Google Calendar will repeat the event correctly, the written description of repeats used in the UI only describes one `RRULE`.

eg. "Weekly on Thursday, until May 15, 2021", not "Weekly on Tuesday & Thursday, until May 15, 2021"